# Why is there not enough information to decide the equivalence of this problem?

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, propositional-calculus

Consider the following question:

> Let α be a formula such that ¬α is a contradictory formula. Consider the formula α ∧ β. Is it contradictory, contingent, tautologous or is there not enough information to decide.

Now the solution that I'm given goes as such, note I broke it into two parts for easier reading:

**Part 1**

> ¬α is contradictory, and thus false on every valuation. Since negation switches trues to falses, α must be true on every valuation, and hence a tautology.

**Part 2**

> Given only this, α ∧ β could be tautologous, contingent, or contradictory, as proved by the following examples:

```
|--------------|-------------|---------------|---------------|
|       α      |      β      |      ¬α       |     α ∧ β     |
|--------------|-------------|---------------|---------------|
|  (P ∨ ¬P )   |  (Q ∨ ¬Q)   | Contradictory |  Tautologous  |
|  (P ∨ ¬P )   |      P      | Contradictory |  Contingent   |
|  (P ∨ ¬P )   |  (P ∧ ¬P)   | Contradictory | Contradictory |
|--------------|-------------|---------------|---------------|
```

> So the correct answer in this case is there not enough information to decide. In fact, as you can prove yourself, α ∧ β will be equivalent to β.

**Thoughts**

Part 1 makes total sense since we know the basic theorem:

> If a formula A is a contradiction, then its negation ~A is a tautology.

I cannot figure out how in part 2 the table was constructed. Primarily the first two columns. How would those formulations in the first two columns lead to the solution? Any help will be appreciated.

**Follow up question**

Let's say we are given another similar question, but this time we are given two formulas:

> Let α and β be formulas such that α → β is a contradictory formula. Consider the formula α ∧ β

**My answer**

Since α → β is contradictory then α must be true and β must be false. Therefore, α ∧ β is contradictory. Summed up with the following table:

```
|--------------|-------------|---------------|---------------|
|       α      |      β      |     α → β     |     α ∧ β     |
|--------------|-------------|---------------|---------------|
|  (P ∨ ¬P )   |  (P ∧ ¬P)   | Contradictory | Contradictory |
|--------------|-------------|---------------|---------------|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first column is just an example – the simplest example, but any example will do – of a tautology.

The second column contains a tautology, a contingent statement, and a contradiction (again, the simplest examples of each).

Now you just have to see that the conjunction of two tautologies is a tautology, and so on.

Comment: Hi, I updated my question with another question. Would my answer be correct?

Comment: It's better to 1) accept one of the answers posted by clicking in the check box next to it, if you feel that answer has answered your (original) question, and 2) post your new question as a new question. But as regards your new question, I think you are confused as to the meaning of that $\vee$ symbol.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in the update. I meant to use a conjunction operator.

Answer (score 0):

If we have that $\neg \alpha$ is a contradiction (i.e. always false), then the negation ($\neg \neg \alpha$ = $\alpha$) of that must mean it's always true (a tautology).

Then $\alpha \wedge \beta$ becomes $1 \wedge \beta = \beta$.

With no more information given to us than in your question, we can clearly see that we have no idea of knowing what $\beta$ is. It can be anything depending on what the expression it represents is. This is what part 2 of your answer goes through, just having different expressions for $\beta$ and then seeing that they can give rise to different answers.

Therefore there can't be enough information to decide the question.